# How to run data in react after useEffect

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I want to run data(all levels) that I destructured from another data(API) and display it into the dom, it works but I got an empty array when I refresh the page

With the code below I got the data

```
//Function to fetch the data from the API
  const GetCourses = async () => {
    const response = await axios.get(url)
    const {data} = response;
    return data;
  }

//UseEffect to run the function on every render
  useEffect(()=> {
    const GetCoursesYoga = async () => {
      const result = await GetCourses();
      setYogaCourses(result);
      setTimeout(() => {setIsLoading(false)}, 1000);
    } 
    GetCoursesYoga();
  }, []);
```

From the data above I want to get all the items with name of levels(beginner-intermidate)

```
const allLevels = [ ...new 
   Set(yogaCourses.map((singleLevel)=> 
   singleLevel.level))];
```

I got an array of a specific item from the array that I want to store in the state below

```
const [levels, setLevels] = useState([]);


useEffect(()=> {
    setLevels(allLevels);
  },[])
```

How I can store the array allLevels in my state setLevels ? assuming that yogaCourses is in state

Thank you

Comment: You problem is not clear. You should share all the components concerned by this issue.

Comment: Assuming `yogaCourses` is in state, you really don't need `setLevels`. You can just use `allLevels` when needed. If you really want to store `allLevels` in state you could do it inside of `GetCoursesYoga`.

Comment: You're right Bafsky yougaCourses is in the state and yes I want to store allLevels in its own state, but when I implemented it inside GetCoursesYoga it works when I console.log but when I refresh the page I got an empty array !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you get the result from the API, you can set it directly to your `useState`

```
useEffect(()=> {
    const GetCoursesYoga = async () => {
      const courses = await GetCourses();
      setYogaCourses(courses.map(course => course.level));
      setTimeout(() => {setIsLoading(false)}, 1000);
    } 
    GetCoursesYoga();
  }, []);
```

Assuming that you have this as well:
`const [yogaCourses, setYogaCourses] = useState([])`

Also,`setTimeout(() => {setIsLoading(false)}, 1000);` is not really great.
What we can do is wait until we actually get the result and when we set the `useState`. So when our `courses` go from `[]` => `['course1', 'course2'...]` etc.

So what we can do is this: (When our yogacourses change value, and if that value is greater than 0, we assume we have some responses and we can stop loading)

```
    useEffect(()=> {
      if(yogaCourses.length > 0){
        setIsLoading(false)
      }
    }, [yogaCourses]);
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I have a simple question is that why when I wanted to store the array allLevels outside of GetCoursesYoga, I got an empty array when I refresh the page ?

Comment: @DavidJay Correct, when you refresh the page and you're logging `yogaCourses` it should be empty array because you've set it as a default here `const [yogaCourses, setYogaCourses] = useState([])`